# How to get twitter bootstrap toggle switch values using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using http://bootstrapswitch.site/ for toggle switch buttons. How can I get the toggle switch like 'on' or 'off' using jQuery?

My Code is :

```
<div class="make-switch  switch-small"><input type="radio" class="nsfw"></div>
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state'); // true || false
$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('toggleState');
```

Refer [this link](http://bootstrapswitch.site/documentation-2.html) for more functions

Comment: $('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('**state**');

Comment: Why $('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state'); will overide the existing widget?

Comment: @janhartmann seems an update have been done, so `$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);` does not work anymore, should be `$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state', false);`

Comment: Fixed @DanielH :-)

Answer (score 17):

As far as I can tell the method has been updated (but not well documented).

```
$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state', true)
$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state', false)
```

Comment: weird, the documentation is still not updated! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: this one works for me, thanks! (seems like an update)

Answer (score 3):

About changing state in my case,

```
('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state', false);
```

It's correct code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#switcher').bootstrapSwitch('state');
```

Not work for me, but in my version:

```js
$("#switcher").bootstrapSwitch("status");
```

can work well.